# How to enable push notifications in AIR app?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, push-notification

Is there a way to enable push notifications in an AIR-enabled app? I have an iOS native app I would like to try and port to AIR, I have the proper provisioning profile and certificate, etc.

thanks,

Comment: Are you talking about RTMP? Longpoll?

Please specify what sort of "push" you want.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Push notifications are not natively supported in AIR, but there are Native Extensions (ANEs) that let you have this functionality.

The guys from Fresh Planet developed several ANEs that are available with an open source license. I, myself, am using the Push Notification ANE they provided.

Check it out:
https://github.com/freshplanet

Answer (score 0):

Push notifications are not supported in AIR till the latest released version 3.3